# sha256 with PHP session

Tags: php, security, session, sha256

New to security and wondering how secure this type of login is?  I am not protecting any bank/financial data by any means but trying to secure somewhat sensitive data that shouldn't be exposed to the general public.  I only require a password - no official logins are done.

This is in a file called access.php which houses a password input field.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
}

// sha256() password 
$password = '13d249f2cb4127b40cfa757866850278793f814ded3c587fe5889e889a7a9f6c';

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (hash('sha256',$_POST['password']) == $password) {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    } else {
        die ('That is the incorrect password - Please leave now');
    }
} 

if (!$_SESSION['loggedIn']):
?>
```

Then my index.php requires access.php at page load.  Should access live outside the public directory?  Am I missing anything else I should be considering?

Comment: [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) - best practice for hashing and checking passwords in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> New to security and wondering how secure this type of login is?

1. SHA-256: You're using the entirely wrong tool for the job. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`:

   - [How to safely store a password](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016)
   - [Cryptography terms explained for non-experts](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded)
2. Additionally, SHA-256 is vulnerable to [length-extension attacks](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks).
3. Using `==` to compare hashes has two vulnerabilities:

   - [Timing attacks](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html)
   - [Magic hash comparison](https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/magic-hashes/) (the more pressing concern)

So, to answer your question: Not very. The problem your code is trying to solve is well-known among security experts, and they've gone out of their way to make it simple for others to solve it. That's why `password_hash()`and `password_verify()` exist. Use them.

That said, welcome to software security. If you need some additional resources to aid your self-education, check out this [application security reading list on Github](https://github.com/paragonie/awesome-appsec).